# Transform code to C from C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem with transform C++ code to C. I tried a lot of possibilities, but none works. How to solve it? Here is my code: 
This is how I use it in C++:

```
void Posun(int &x, int &y) //posun gulicky
{
        if (y == 1)
                x != 10 ? x++ : y++;
        else if (y == 11)
                x != 1 ? x-- : y--;
        else if (x == 1)
                y != 1 ? y-- : x++;
        else
                y != 11 ? y++ : x--;
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
int Roll(int **grid, int riadky, int stlpce)//roll, vracia padnute cislo
{
        srand(time(NULL));

        int x = (rand() % 10 + 1) > 5 ? 10 : 1;
        int y = rand() % 11 + 1;
        int o = rand() % 50 + 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
        {
                //Clr();
                Posun(&x,&y);
                //VypisGrid(grid, riadky, stlpce, x, y);
                printf("%d,%d", x, y);
                Sleep(100);
        }

        if (x == 1)
                return y > 1 && y < 11 ? grid[y - 1][x - 1] : grid[y - 1][x];

        else if (x == 10)
                return y > 1 && y < 11 ? grid[y - 1][x + 1] : grid[y - 1][x];

        if (y == 1 || y == 11)
                return grid[y - 1][x];
}
```

With this, I get output like: `410,510,610,710,810,910,1010,119,118,117 ....`

But when I try to run this in C compiler I have to remove & from first function so it looks like this:

```
void Posun(int x, int y) 
{
```

And I get output like this: `510,510,510,510,510,510,510` - It's only the final position.

Comment: Do you know why the ampersand is there in the first place? Removing it leaves the same semantics in C and C++.

Comment: The poster had a similar problem, it is already answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no references in C, you have to use pointers like this:

```
void Posun(int* x, int* y) {
    if (*y == 1)
            *x != 10 ? (*x)++ : (*y)++;
    else if (*y == 11)
            *x != 1 ? (*x)-- : (*y)--;
    else if (*x == 1)
            *y != 1 ? (*y)-- : (*x)++;
    else
            *y != 11 ? (*y)++ : (*x)--;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Posun(&x, &y);
```

Comment: I try this for 50 times but i never tried to add () it works perfectly thank you ver much :)

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no references. It allows only call by value. You should declare it as

```
 void Posun(int *x, int *y)
```

and call your function as

```
 Posun(&x, &y);
```

Ans dereference `x` and `y` inside your function using operator `*`

```
*x != 10 ? (*x)++ : (*y)++;
```

Comment: I would say there's still pass-by-reference, just no references. Pass-by-reference is language-dependent.

Comment: @chris; In C, arguments are passed by value unlike C++ in which you can.

Comment: Yes, but to a lot of C programmers, pass-by-reference means passing pointers.

Comment: @chris; Agreed. Pass by reference does't mean that passing a pointer. You are still passing a value.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ code doesn't even compile as it is, but in C you want to use pointers:

```
void Posun(int * x, int * y)
{
    ++*x;
    --*y;
}
```

Usage:

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
Posun(&x, &y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using pointers instead of references.

```
void Posun(int *x, int *y) {...}
```

The address operator `&` does not have the same meaning as `(someType)&`, a reference in C++.